Is std::byte the right data type for hardware registers in an emulator?
I'm writing an emulator for a very popular handheld console in Modern C++.
It's clear that for the RAM I want to use std::vector<std::byte>, but I'm struggling if std::byte is also the correct type for all kinds of registers (CPU registers, hardware registers etc.). In the case of the CPU registers it's very ambigous, but I clearly tend to use std::uint8_t (and std::uint16_t) here, because CPU registers are mainly used for arithmetics. But there are also some sort of „control registers“ that are not used for arithmetics, but store either flags or counters.
Another possible usage of std::byte would be to store the current instruction (that is encoded in one or more bytes).
I also come to an inconsistency because a std::byte only holds 8 bit. But a control registers could also be longer than 8 bits (for example the cr0 register of the IA32 architecture).
Maybe I'm just overthinking this, but it's not clear for me if this is a valid usage for std::byte. The standard says that „std::byte models a mere collection of bits“, but I could argue that a register is cleary more than a „mere collection of bits“, even if it's a control register that contains flags that are one or bits long.

The type should match the bit width of the register.  Use uint32_t for 32-bit registers, etc.

So I should generally use std::uint8_t if it's a 8-bit register and not std::byte?

Yes, use the bit-width types.  IMHO, using a bit-width type with a hardware register is easier to read and will have less issues.

IMO std::byte is a useless type that should never be used for anything, and serves no purpose.  If your memory is organized as 8-bit chunks, you should use std:uint8_t

Hardware/CPU registers should use a type which is the same width as the register, and not an array of uint8_t.
The reason is that CPU registers that are more than one byte wide are not (generally) byte addressable.  If your register is 32 bits/4 bytes wide, you can't just reference reg1_[0], assuming reg_1 is defined as an array of 4 uint8_t.  To grab a byte from a multi-byte register requires masking and shifting the register contents.
Note that I'm basing this on CPUs like x86, PowerPC and the like.  I don't know about ARM.
